# What does the variable $\tau$ mean in frequency modulation?

Tags: continuous-signals, frequency-modulation

Frequency modulation formula:

$$
x_{FM}(t) = A_{c}\cos\left(2\pi f_{c} t+ 2\pi k_{f}\displaystyle\int_0^{t}m(\tau)d\tau+\phi_{0}\right)
$$

Its change from $m(t)$ to $m(\tau)$.
What is $\tau$? I wonder what it means.

Comment: that is... basic math, not signal processing. That's the integration variable; I'm sure you've seen an integral before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a dummy integration variable. The time variable $t$ is the upper integration limit, so you can't use it as the integration variable. An expression like

$\int_0^tm(t)dt\qquad(???)\tag{1}$

doesn't make sense, whereas

$$\int_0^tm(x)dx\tag{2}$$

does.

Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109105/70664) and its answers over at math.SE.